# Setting up a wemake-python-styleguide GitHub action that respects a legacy code flakehell baseline

Tags: python, yaml, github-actions, flake8

#### Problem

I want to to set up a **GitHub Action that runs the [`wemake-python-styleguide`](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/integrations/github-actions.html) on every push to the repo, but respects a legacy code [`flakehell`](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/integrations/flakehell.html) baseline**.

According to the wemake-python-styleguide Website,
[*"flakehell is officially supported by wemake-python-styleguide and developed by the same people"*](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/integrations/flakehell.html).

My problem is: All the GitHub Action workflow file (`.yml`) specifications I've tried so far, did not work.

#### Setup

First, I set a `flakehellbaseline` locally via `flakehell > .flakehellbaseline` and put the

```
[tool.flakehell]
baseline = ".flakehell_baseline"
```

in my `pyproject.toml`. Pushed everything to the repo.

#### Github action workflow specification

**1.) Attempt**

Then I created a new GitHub Action workflow file (`wemakepython.yml`) according to their [premade Github Action](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/integrations/github-actions.html).

```
name: wemakepython

on: push

jobs:
  wemake:
      runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
      steps:
        - name: wemake-python-styleguide
          uses: wemake-services/wemake-python-styleguide@0.14.0
```

Result:

[image]

The action gets triggered, and runs through smoothly. **But**, it does not report any `flake8` or `flakehell lint` violations, despite there being plenty of them. How do I know that? If I run either `flakehell lint` or `flake8 .` locally, there are plenty of violations.

**2.) Attempt**

If the `wemake-python-styleguide` premade GitHub Action does not work, I'll just specify a `flakehell.yml` GitHub Action by myself.

```
name: flakehell

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: flakehell-linter
        run: |
          pip install flakehell
          flakehell lint
```

Result:

Unfortunately this one doesn't work either. The action does not even run, it exits with error code 1.

```
@github-actions
github-actions
/ build

.github#L1
Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Any ideas how to solve this? May it be a problem with the `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml` definitions?